# Getting 415(unsupported media type ) in ajax formdata post resuest to spring

Tags: angularjs, ajax, spring-mvc, angularjs-http

Want to send image data through ajax to the controller .But error 415 gets .I am using angular js and send images to the controller . But error ocurs . Please help

```
        fd= new FormData();                 
        fd.append("image", imageall);                            
        call(fd);
    });
}

function call(fd){
    $http({        
         method: 'POST',
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         url: "./WQF00069/update.app",
         data: fd,
         processData: false,
         enctype:'multipart/form-data',
         transformRequest: angular.identity,
         cache: false,
         timeout: 600000,
         headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined},
     }).success(function(data) {
         Flash.create('info', ' Update Success Fully ', 'large-text');
         `enter code here`
     }).error(function(response){ 
         console.dir(response);
        Flash.create('danger','There is a  Problem.Contact With Administrator', 'large-text');       
     });
}
```

Comment: Why the `'Content-Type': undefined`? What is `enctype:'multipart/form-data'`

Comment: The `.success` method has been [removed from the AngularJS framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35329384/why-are-angularjs-http-success-error-methods-deprecated-removed-from-v1-6/35331339#35331339). The `processData`, `enctype`, and `contentType` are jQuery properties and are ignored by the [$http Service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#$http-arguments).